# creating fake LDAP server in a c program

Tags: c, ldap

We have a project that requires us to create a fake ldap server. We really don't know how to create or understand fully what is it.

Can someone explain it to us and how to include it in our C program? Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LDAP is an authentication database, storing names and password in a tree.

There is a root, which is called the base, then you have subtrees, with groups or people in it.

For example you have : http://www.klocwork.com/products/documentation/cliffhanger/images/f/ff/Ldap_tree.png

This is for the structure.

Now you have an idea, you have to make some kind of API to create with commands.
On LDAP you use ldapadd to add a node in your tree, or directly a person.
Usually you put the information of where you want to add the node, or the person in a file you give as input for your command such as :
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LDAP_Data_Interchange_Format

Ok, so you have basically your LDAP now, but the main point of it is still not done.
Now you need it to answer when a login is called.

For example you have a site that requires a login/password, and this site is connected to your fake LDAP, when you press the login button, your site or program should call your LDAP server and check that the information are correct.

Features you should add:
Look up for access rights by people
make encryption communication between your site/program and LDAP

I would recommend to look up for more information in the documentation :)

http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/

EDIT: 
I'm not sure that's what you wanted. If it's the other way around, it means your C program need a login/password and call an LDAP server then.